# How to avoid circular references with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following models (and corresponding DTOs):

```
public class Link
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int FirstLinkId {get; set;}
    public int SecondLinkId {get; set;}
    public virtual Link FirstLink {get; set;}
    public virtual Link SecondLInk {get; set;}
}

public class OtherObject
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int LinkId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Link Link {get; set;}
}
```

In my scenario, I can have a `Link` object where `FirstLink` and/or `SecondLink` can be null, references to other objects, or references to the same object.

Now I want to load an `OtherObject` entity from the db using EF. I load the entity itself and also the `Link` object associated with it. This is done perfectly by EF.

In this particular case, both `FirstLink` and `SecondLink` are the same as `Link`, therefore, when automapping from model to dto it just keeps on mapping into oblivion.

My mapping is:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OtherObject, OtherObjectDto>().Bidirectional()
      .ForMember(model => model.LinkId, option => option.Ignore());
```

where Bidirectional() is this extension:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TDestination, TSource> Bidirectional<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    return Mapper.CreateMap<TDestination, TSource>();
}
```

Is there way to tell Automapper not to map further down the tree in this case?

Comment: Try turning on the viewstate for the viewer

Comment: One little thing - do ReverseMap instead of Bidirectional, that is already built in.

Answer (score 8):

The way I would handle this is to create separate DTO objects for the children:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Employee Supervisor {get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeDto {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SupervisorDto Supervisor { get; set; }

    public class SupervisorDto {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto.SupervisorDto>();
```

Don't let your DTOs be recursive/self-referential. Be explicit in your structure on how deep you want it to go.

EF can't do recursive joins, you're only doing one level, so don't make your DTOs go nuts with infinitely deep relationships. Be explicit.

Comment: This reminds me of a project I worked on recently. I had non-EF domain objects with a one-many relationship that I needed to map to application-level DTOs and return to the client, without using JSON references. On the domain, I used the mutator on the settee to set a reference to itself on the setter. Mapping was okay because the mutator behavior did not exist on the DTOs. The relationship was mapped correctly. The client serializer was where I specified the level of recursion. Smelly? Or okay, because the proper place to dictate the depth was the client?

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party, but could you please give an example on how to use this when Supervisor was an ICollection<SupervisorDto> ??