# Map components of DTO which are DTOs as well

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

This is my class which holds database data:

```
public partial class PermissionGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other database properties

    public virtual ICollection<GroupActionPermission> GroupActionPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

And that's my dto's:

```
public class PermissionGroupDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GroupActionPermissionDTO> ActionPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class GroupActionPermissionDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int PermissionActionId { get; set; }

    public PermissionGroupDTO Group { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am making mapping:

```
public IEnumerable<PermissionGroupDTO> GetGroups()
{
    return OnConnect<IEnumerable<PermissionGroupDTO>>(db =>
    {
        return db.PermissionGroups
        .Include(i => i.GroupActionPermissions)
        .ProjectTo<PermissionGroupDTO>()
        .ToList();
    });
}
```

And I am getting collection of `PermissionGroupDTO` which should contains collection of `GroupActionPermissionDTO`, but that collection stays `null`. Is there something wrong with my code? I am afraid that `automapper` can map collections from foreign keys.

Also, thats my automapper initializer:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<PermissionGroup, PermissionGroupDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<GroupActionPermission, GroupActionPermissionDTO>();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason is desribed here http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

> Note that for this feature to work, all type conversions must be explicitly handled in your Mapping.

So that means you should manually configure the mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<PermissionGroup, PermissionGroupDTO>()
       .ForMember(dto => dto.ActionPermissions , conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.GroupActionPermissions )));;
    cfg.CreateMap<GroupActionPermission, GroupActionPermissionDTO>();
});
```

BTW, note that fields are named differently: *GroupActionPermissions* vs. *ActionPermissions*. This is also the reason why automapper doesn't map it automatically and then you should use the manual configuration I wrote.

Comment: Now its working. I have access to `GroupActionPermissionDTO`. But I have no access to `actionPermission.Group`, even with: `cfg.CreateMap<GroupActionPermission, GroupActionPermissionDTO>()
.ForMember(x => x.Group, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.PermissionGroup));`

Comment: You mean it works with my solution? And what is this that doesn't work? The way upwards, from groupActionPermission to permission group?

Comment: Yes, with your solution it works (`permissionGroup.ActionPermissions` is not `null`). The problem is I want to have access backwards, but `permissionGroup.ActionPermissions.Group` stays `null`. I added `ForMember`, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I may guess that this is done on purpose because otherwise you'll have a circular reference.

Comment: Could that http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#circular-references be of any help? And this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763042/how-to-avoid-circular-references-with-automapper

Comment: Unfrotunelly thats not helping. Nothing changed. Whats more, after repairing some naming I am getting errors: `System.NotSupportedException: 'The type 'PermissionActionDTO' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.'`. I set properties in same places, but not working anyways.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is done on purpose, i.e. Automapper sees that he's already mapped that. Maybe it's worth to be extracted as a separate question? If yes, may I ask you to check you question as answered?

Comment: But look, in first scenario I need to have access to `UserDTO.OrdersDTO.BookDTO.AuthorDTO.FirstName`, and in second scanario I want to get all authors' book. Because of that I need to have reference from `AuthorDTO` to `BookDTO`. That is giving me a cycle in first scenario. Should create 2 different view models for this?